# JAXB project to be compiled with JDK SE 8 but has to run also on JRE 11

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I have a Java program I compile in Java 1.8 because it has - between others - because many users only have JRE 1.8. In that program I use javax.xml.bind.* quite often to marshall and unmarshall XML. To help users run it on JRE 9-10, I also provided a shell script that calls java with the `-add-modules` argument. For users that have Java 11+ (and no previous Java version installed), that won't work, will it?

So I thought of bundling JAXB (or EclipseLink Moxy) with my program and still compile it with JDK8 (with Eclipse IDE). So that I runs on Java 8 and still on Java 11+. Will that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested it? Also if you use tool like Maven (as one of the answers assume) you could created separate profiles to add dependencies when it is Java 8,9 10-> etc...

Comment: Thank you! I failed at adding Jakarta XML Binding into my project in the Eclipse IDE. I do not use maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments and answers!

I finally got it running, though it is not perfect yet. This is what I did:

1. downloaded Jakarta JAXB 2.3.2 here: [maven](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.3/jaxb-ri-2.3.3.zip)
2. unzipped it and put the content to my project directory
3. in Eclipse IDE 2020-6, I edited the properties of the project (Cmd+I):
4. Under the topic "Java Build Path", I added 3 jars with "Add External JAR": jaxb-impl.jar, jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar and jakarta.activation.jar
5. The part I obviously forgot before: also under "order and export", I checked that 3 JARs.

To test the result, I told Eclipse IDE under "Run/Debug", register "JRE" to run my main class with JRE 12.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

here a solution add these dependencies to your pom.xml ( if u re using) maven :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the code will compile in both version java 8 and 11.

Comment: No, I do not use maven. But I can try to add it into my project at Eclipse IDE. Thank you! I downloaded Jakarta JAXB-RI. I do not know what to add. There is a jaxb-impl.jar and a jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar, but I cannot find a jaxb-core?

Comment: here the link for jaxb-core https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/3.0.0-M4  and you also to add jaxb-api and jaxb-impl jars